# Trying to make command like "Shell" with commands with RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, shell, terminal

Trying to make command like `Shell` with commands with RichTextBox.

Can anyone make a simple way to make it?
im searching for this on entire webs can't find a way to make it.
So its should be like any terminal / shell / console app
So i can simply add custom commands like whatismyip its shows me my ip address etc.

Should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBbn7.png).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
  For I As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1 
    Dim Parts() As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(I).Split 
    Select Case Parts(0).ToUpper 
      Case "getip" 
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("SYS $~ 127.0.0.1") 
      Case Else 
        RichTextBox1.AppendText("SYS $~ Invalid command.") 
    End Select 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: If that is all the conditions you have that should be a simple `If/Else` not a `Select Case`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    commands = New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of String, IEnumerable(Of String), String))() From _
    { _
        {"getip", Function(c, ps) Me.GetIP().ToString()}, _
        {"nop", Function(c, ps) "No Command"} _
    }
End Sub

Private commands As Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of String, IEnumerable(Of String), String)) = Nothing

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim command = {"nop"}.Concat(Me.RichTextBox1.Lines) _
                  .Reverse().First(Function(l) Not [String].IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))

    If (If(Me.RichTextBox1.Lines.LastOrDefault(), "")).Length > 0 Then
        Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
    End If

    Dim parts = command.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim result = "Invalid Command"
    If commands.ContainsKey(parts(0).ToLower()) Then
        result = commands(parts(0))(parts(0), parts.Skip(1).ToArray())
    End If
    Me.RichTextBox1.AppendText("SYS $~ " + result)
End Sub

Private Function GetIP() As String
    Dim host As IPHostEntry
    Dim localIP As String = "?"
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
    For Each ip As IPAddress In host.AddressList
        If ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            localIP = ip.ToString()
        End If
    Next
    Return localIP
End Function
```

You'll need to add the following imports:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
```

Then you can just build out the dictionary for each of your commands.

Comment: Thank your @Enigmativity.
Can it be provided with prefix? i mean like dim user
so its will be command split as: Userpc $~ getip
and what about arguments?

Comment: @Shahar - I don't know what you mean by a prefix. Is it the `"SYS $~ "`? This code currently handles arguments - that's the `Func(Of String, IEnumerable(Of String), String)` signature. The `Func` takes a `String` (the command) and `IEnumerable(Of String)` (the list of `' '` separated arguments from the command).